# Is there any faster way than Eigensystem to diagonalize a Hermitian matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Is there any faster way than using `Eigensystem` to diagonalize (get all the eigenvectors and eigenvalues) of a Hermitian (self-adjoint) matrix?

That would be amazing :).

Thanks.

Comment: You are talking about matrices with numbers as elements, right?

Comment: @halirutan , yes indeed, complex numbers in general.

Comment: In the case where it is positive definite, possibly diagonalizing, via eigensystem, a Cholesky factor might give a speed boost.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer is no. `Eigensystem` already uses faster algorithms for Hermitian matrices. See what happens when I add a small non-Hermitian matrix:

```
n = 1000;

m = RandomComplex[1 + I, {n, n}];
h = m + ConjugateTranspose[m];
d = 10^-10 RandomComplex[1 + I, {n, n}];

Eigensystem[h]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.971269, Null} *)

Eigensystem[h + d]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {14.567275, Null} *)
```

Comment: A query after your helpful answer. Is there a chance where Mathematica assumes Matrix not to be Hermitian, even though it is Hermitian?(This is what happened with me)

Comment: @L.K. Your matrix can be Hermitian up to some numerical precision depending on your previous computations. You can make it Hermitian in a strict sense with `h = (h + ConjugateTranspose[h])/2`.