# How to tell Eigensystem the type of the elements comprising a matrix I would like to diagonalize

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I tell `Eigensystem` that a matrix $M$, which I would like to diagonalize, is a numerical matrix of complex numbers? My idea is that this information could speed up the calculation, since *Mathematica* would not need to determine the type of the matrix.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. Are you trying to find a symbolic solution first by using assumptions, or do you want to define a function that takes a numerical argument and returns the `Eigensystem`, or is `M` already numerical but written in terms of arbitrary-precision numbers, or something else? Please include a minimum example to clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: You are already given M. Let's say M=RandomReal[{0,1},{1000,1000}]. Since you know in this case this matrix is made of real numbers (numeric, no symbols) how do you pass this information to eigensystem to speed up the computation?

Comment: For example, myeig = Compile[{{mat, _Complex, 2}}, 
   Eigenvalues[mat], {{Eigenvalues[_], _Complex, 1}}, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, CompilationTarget -> "C"]; will speed up the computation of eigenvalues of a matrix of complex numbers. But I couldn't generalize this to use Eigensystem.

Comment: @Iagoa: What you are looking for does not exist, to my knowledge. In particular, `Eigenvalues` is not a compilable function, since it is outsourced to a backend LAPACK/BLAS solver that operates independently of Mathematica. Likewise, you can't tell it to use `CompilationTarget -> "C"` because the computations are not being done in C, but are done by LAPACK. For more information, see `tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation` and the section "Approximate Numerical Linear Algebra".

Comment: Beyond that, I personally don't know how the internals work. I *have* noticed that Mathematica seems to auto-detect Hermiticity, symmetry, and other matrix properties when `Eigenvalues` is called: for example, calling `Eigenvalues` on an approximate complex Hermitian matrix returns a list of purely-real floating point numbers, with no machine-precision-size complex parts present. Other than that, I can't say what sort of auto-detection is or isn't occurring. Perhaps someone else with more knowledge can chime in with more info.

Comment: Related: [Is there any faster way than Eigensystem to diagonalize a Hermitian matrix?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40847/4678)

Comment: Your gravatar is a near-twin of mine. I am surprised I never noticed this before since you have been participating in _Mathematica_.SE for well over a year. However, I only noticed now when I saw my gravatar next to yours after editing this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Eigensystem` is already informed

```
A = RandomReal[1, {1000, 1000}];
A += Transpose[A];

Eigensystem[A]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.034878, Null} *)

Eigensystem[A + 0. I]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.645509, Null} *)
```

---

*Update:* type detection timings:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];

r = RandomReal[1, {100, 100}];
c = RandomComplex[1 + I, {100, 100}];

MatrixQ[r, Internal`RealValuedNumericQ] // AccurateTiming
MatrixQ[c, Internal`RealValuedNumericQ] // AccurateTiming
(* 8.60352*10^-7 *)
(* 8.61328*10^-7 *)

r = RandomReal[1, {1000, 1000}];
c = RandomComplex[1 + I, {1000, 1000}];

MatrixQ[r, Internal`RealValuedNumericQ] // AccurateTiming
MatrixQ[c, Internal`RealValuedNumericQ] // AccurateTiming
(* 8.4375*10^-7 *)
(* 8.92578*10^-7 *)
```

0.9 microsecond is fast enough to forget about it. Moreover, the timing doesn't depend on the matrix size because matrices are packed with the proper information about the type

```
r // Developer`PackedArrayForm
c // Developer`PackedArrayForm

(* PackedArray[Real, <1000, 1000>] *)
(* PackedArray[Complex, <1000, 1000>] *)
```

Comment: Not really. For sure  Eigensystem spends some time figuring out what type of matrix you provided.

Comment: @lagoa But that time is negligible compared to the computation of the eigensystem.

Comment: What @Jens said. Especially if dimension is in the several hundreds or more.

Comment: What about for matrices with dimension 16000?